# Upside-down triangle symbol on function

Tags: definition

I came across the symbol that looks like an upside-down triangle, and coming in front of a function $f(x,y)$. What does that mean?

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla$?

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes! That one.

Comment: It likely refers to the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: The symbol's name is [nabla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol) or [del](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upside-down triangle is likely a *gradient* operator in this context:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\hat{x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\hat{y}.$$